# How to get the reference of a cell based on two filters in Google Sheets?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, google-sheets-formula

I am parsing JSON data from a FB Ads Campaign through Graph API in Google Sheets. I have multiple sheets for different ad insights based on a timeframe (today, yesterday, 7 days, 30 days) and a dashboard that shows a snapshot of the most important data like the # of conversions and cost-per-conversion for each campaign.

On the dashboard page, I want to match the Adset ID with the value next to cells that contain 'complete_registration' on an insight page.

This is the current formula I have
=INDIRECT(INDEX("h"&filter(ROW('Todays Insights'!G1:G901),'Todays Insights'!G1:G901="complete_registration")),1)

This works for referencing the first time 'complete registration' is used... but I want the value for each Adset

For example -> IF Column A has Adset_ID and Column B has Complete registration then index value in C

What formula would accomplish this in Google Sheets?

[Picture Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fT95w.jpg)

Comment: Hi. Would you share a sheet with this example? It's hard to help without it.

Comment: I have added a picture. Thank you!   https://i.stack.imgur.com/fT95w.jpg

Answer (score 0):

O.K. I think I get it. You want to get 2 coulmns as a result - B and column H when C is registration_complete.

Try:

```
=filter({'Todays Insights'!a1:a,'Todays Insights'!h1:h},'Todays Insights'!c1:c="complete_registration")
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried your formula, but it didn't seem to pull the right info. Here is the formula that ended up working for me: =DGET('Sheet Name'!$A$1:$N$500,"Actions Value",{"Adset ID","Actions Action Type";C24,"lead"})

Answer (score 0):

Here is the formula I used that works:
=DGET('Sheet Name'!$A$1:$N$500,"Actions Value",{"Adset ID","Actions Action Type";C24,"lead"})